# How do I make a loop that echos symbols without /n

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a automatic batch file game generator, because animating the game manually is much too slow. I ran into a problem while I was programming to try to achieve this. My problem was that I couldn't figure out how to continuously "stack" symbols one on top of the other using the command echo. Here is an example of what I want to happen:

1. Variable is set to #
2. Program loops back and it is now set to ##
3. Program loops until specified amount is reached(Such as 51 in one variable of the symbol #)

This is all I wrote before I was stuck.
(Note: I was trying to make my program make 2 variables for 2 lines of symbols)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:GroundCreationLoop
set loopcontrol=51
set groundholder=# 
set groundholder2=# 
echo !groundholder! 
echo !groundholder2!
if !loopcontrol!==51
```

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. You want all the `#` to print on one line, correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set char=#
for /l %%a in (1,1,51) do (
echo !char!
set char=!char!#
)
pause >nul
```

Outputs

```
# 
## 
### 
#### 
##### 
###### 
####### 
######## 
######### 
########## 
########### 
############ 
############# 
############## 
############### 
################ 
################# 
################## 
################### 
#################### 
##################### 
###################### 
####################### 
######################## 
######################### 
########################## 
########################### 
############################ 
############################# 
############################## 
############################### 
################################ 
################################# 
################################## 
################################### 
#################################### 
##################################### 
###################################### 
####################################### 
######################################## 
######################################### 
########################################## 
########################################### 
############################################ 
############################################# 
############################################## 
############################################### 
################################################ 
################################################# 
################################################## 
###################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here's a batch script that will do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set start=0
set end=51
set char=#
:loop
    if %start%==%end% goto stop
    set /a start=%start%+1
    echo %char%
    set char=#%char%
goto loop
:stop
```

In this case, char keeps accumulating #, which gives you a right triangle made up of #'s.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command to echo without a newline at the end is `echo|set /P=(your thing)` so if you wanted to print 51 "#" symbols in a row you'd have to use `echo|set /P=!groundholder!`. Also, are you missing a `goto GroundCreationLoop`?

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set loopcontrol = 0
set groundholder = #

:GroundCreationLoop
    set /a loopcontrol = %loopcontrol% + 1
    echo|set /P = %groundholder%
    if not %loopcontrol% == 51 goto GroundCreationLoop
```

Comment: You should avoid spaces in `SET` statements, as they count to the variable name. `echo|set /p ..` works but it starts two new cmd.exe contexts each time, therefore it's better to use `<nul set /p ...`

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this using a VB Script as a helper function.

Create `PromptHelper.vbs` with these contents:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("PROMPT") Then
  WScript.StdOut.Write WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("PROMPT")
End If
```

Then, in your batch script, replace the `ECHO` with a call to `PromptHelper.vbs`.

For example:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET loopcontrol=0

:GroundCreationLoop
  SET /A loopcontrol=!loopcontrol! + 1
  CSCRIPT C:\Scripts\PromptHelper.vbs /PROMPT:#
  IF NOT !loopcontrol! == 51 GOTO GroundCreationLoop

ECHO.
```

The `ECHO.` at the bottom will send you to the beginning of the next line.